# Show that $n^2$ divides $(n+1)^n -1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I've tried to prove by induction

For $n = 1,(1+1)^1 - 1 = 1$ and $1 / 1$.

For $k\in\Bbb N$ we have $k^2 / (k+1)^k - 1$.

For $k+1$,   $$(k+2)^{k+1} - 1,$$

$$(k+2)(k+2)^k - 1 $$

This is the far a i could get. I've tried some aproaches such as expanding but i couldn't do it.

Comment: Hint: use binomial expansion,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the binomial theorem, we have $$(n+1)^n-1=\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkn^k\right)-1=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nkn^k$$ Now, every summand for $k\geq 2$ in the big sum is obviously divisible by $n^2$. For $k=1$, $\binom n1n^1=n^2$ is divisible by $n^2$ as well, so the whole expression is divisible by $n^2$.

Comment: Is there any insight into why this works, I plugged 2 into the original question, and it is true for 2.  Is there an intuitive explanation for this?  The question as posed certainly doesn't *look* like it is true, even though apparently it is.

Comment: Just as the answer indicates, the issue critically depends on the fact that $$(n^2) ~\text{divides} ~\left[ ~\binom{n}{1} \times \left(n^1\right) ~\right].$$